# How to delete a user in Ubuntu but keep his home dir?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to delete a user, but I need to keep his home dir.

I tried `userdel -r user`, but this also removes his home dir.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: "I tried" is not enough if you try blindly and without researching. Even a quick scan of "`userdel`"s manual would tell you that you are asking it to remove the home directory by giving `-r`.

Answer (score 14):

The `-r` does the exact opposite of what you want. From `userdel --help`:

```
-r, --remove    remove home directory and mail spool
```

Instead of `userdel -r user`, just use:

```
userdel user
```

Comment: Note: userdel will delete the group with the same name as the user.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

Use the deluser command.

However, before doing so check the file /etc/deluser.conf

And check the line

```
# Remove home directory and mail spool when user is removed
REMOVE_HOME = 0
```

Ensure this to 0 (not 1) before calling deluser.

**Option 2:**

sudo vipw
Find the entry you want to remove (first part of the line up to the first ':' is the username).  Then type "dd" to remove the entire line.

Save and exit with "esc + wq".